# Is it possible to create a function in Haskell which returns a list of the constructors for a data type?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, dynamic-programming, template-haskell

Is it possible to create a function in Haskell which returns a list of the constructors for a data type?

It should work like this:

```
ghci> getConstructors Bool
[True, False]
ghci> getConstructors Maybe
[Nothing, Just]
```

Comment: let's assume for a moment that `Bool` and `Maybe` where values of some type - already for `Maybe` your resulting list would have one element of type `Maybe a` and one of type `a -> Maybe a` so it would not be a valid list - having said this: you probably get something very similar by using [Typeable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html)

Comment: The `Data` typeclass has something along those lines, but it's terrifying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think about this: what would be the type of the list? `Nothing` has type `Maybe a` but `Just` has type `a -> Maybe a`.

You can look at generics though. Using the package `syb`:

```
Prelude> import Data.Data
Prelude Data.Data> dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf (Just 4)
[Nothing,Just]
```

Note that here `[Nothing,Just]` is just how it's printed on screen, it's not actually a list containing the two constructors.

```
Prelude Data.Data> :t dataTypeConstrs (dataTypeOf (Just 4))
dataTypeConstrs (dataTypeOf (Just 4)) :: [Constr]
```

Anyway, having a list with `[Nothing,Just]` (even if that was correct Haskell) would not be really useful. You wouldn't be able to do anything with the values inside it as you wouldn't know their types.